# Need to reload content script for chrome extension on facebook

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome extension that adds links to items (things your friends share with you) on your facebook feed. Facebook loads about 10 or 20 items on the feed on page load, and then the rest are loaded via ajax when you scroll down.

I managed to get my content script to work for the first items, but not for the rest. I've read everything i could find, and it seems that I have to reload my content script.

How can i do that considering that the URL does not change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) with the [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) event to listen for new items getting rendered in the feed. The callback will have to check each node insertion to see if it is a feed item or not. Something like the following should work.

```
function nodeInsertedCallback(event) { console.log(event); });
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can hang some time driven listener that runs every XX seconds, to verify if there's new items to work with.

Unfortunately there's no event you can hang from, fired when the page's code do some Ajax.

May be you can figure out what evet you can han from to detect the user has reached the end of the loaded item's list, knowing that de page's code will do some Ajax to retrieve more items.  Then you start you time driven listenter.